# Sending mime message containing any of these attachment,htmlbody ,inline image or all of them?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, mime, mime-message

As of know my email application was supporting only plain text with attachments. I was handling it in a simple way if attachment list is null,
simply send the mime message and if attchment list is not  null, i was creating body part for each attachment and one for body. Adding them
in multipart which is set in to mime message.

But now need to support the html part and inline images(where images will be sent as attachment
and html body will be referreing).I know the basics of mime i.e  how to create the body parts for each mime type. But really i am  not getting
how to create the body parts at run timw when i do not what body and attachment list will contain. For example body can contain only plain
text or html body or html body with attachment or html body with inline image with attachment or plain body with attchment.

Frankly i am not getting
how to process the emailbody and attachment list for above mentioned permuations and combinations.(for example some time i need to create top
message as multipart/mixed containg body parts as mulipart/alternative and another body part plain, bla bla....). **Is there standard
code handling these all scenarios based on body content and attachment list. Please point me in right direction?**

here is the  old method signature which was supporting only plain text with attachments

```
  public void sendMimeEmail(List toMailAddresses,
  String fromMailAddress,   String body, List<AttachmentData> attachments) {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any magic here.  You just need enough "if" statements to cover the cases.

Comment: Bill. as per my understanding  to achieve this best way is parse the message body and see if html tag  or html tag with cid exist. If exist set the mime message as multipart/alternative or multipart/related. This kind of logic. RIGHT?

Comment: Usually I would expect your program to know whether the message body is intended to be html or plain text.  If you have to guess, it's up to you to come up with heuristics you like.  Are you collecting the message body text as input from a user?

Comment: Yes i am collecting the message body text as input from a user.What i am  planning is everytime treat the text as html and then make message as alternative so that email clients that does not support html text,can pick up the text/plain part?

Comment: Yes, that will work, but you'll need to convert the user-entered html text into plain text yourself; JavaMail isn't going to help you with that.