# unable to attach MimeMultiPart to Transport.send()

Tags: java, email, gmail, transport

I am trying to send an email with java but I keep getting an `IOException`
any idea what i'm doing wrong? I think it is something with t.send not being `Transport.send()` but I couldn't seem to get it to work I kept getting could not connect errors after that..
any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
public void Send(String recipientEmail) throws AddressException, MessagingException {
    Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
    final String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";
    String title = titleBox.getText();
    // Get a Properties object
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.smtps.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtps.auth", "true");


    props.put("mail.smtps.quitwait", "false");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
    String ccEmail = "";
    // -- Create a new message --
    final MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

    // -- Set the FROM and TO fields --
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(emailUsername + "@gmail.com"));
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipientEmail, false));

    if (ccEmail.length() > 0) {
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse(ccEmail, false));
    }
    String message = messageBox.getText();
    msg.setSubject(title);
    MimeBodyPart messagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
    messagePart.setText(message);
    multipart.addBodyPart(messagePart);
    //msg.setText(message, "utf-8");
    msg.setSentDate(new Date());
    msg.setContent(multipart);
    SMTPTransport t = (SMTPTransport)session.getTransport("smtps");

    t.connect("smtp.gmail.com", emailUsername, emailPassword);
    t.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
    //Transport.send(msg);
    t.close();
}
```

---

I am able to ping smtp.gmail.com correctly the connection issues I believe were due to using `Transport.send()` also this worked before I started using MultiParts because i had sent emails using it before

---

here is the stack trace

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
   nested exception is:
javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type multipart/mixed; 
boundary="----=_Part_0_1039039084.1386965872274"
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:676)
at examples.ContactEditor.Send(ContactEditor.java:445)
at examples.ContactEditor.jButton7ActionPerformed(ContactEditor.java:395)
at examples.ContactEditor.access$400(ContactEditor.java:53)
at examples.ContactEditor$5.actionPerformed(ContactEditor.java:249)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type multipart/mixed; 
boundary="----=_Part_0_1039039084.1386965872274"
at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:891)
at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:317)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1403)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1745)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:636)
... 40 more
```

---

if i use the `static Transport.send()` it gives me the following exception..

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1391)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:412)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:288)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
at examples.ContactEditor.Send(ContactEditor.java:446)
at examples.ContactEditor.jButton7ActionPerformed(ContactEditor.java:396)
at examples.ContactEditor.access$400(ContactEditor.java:53)
at examples.ContactEditor$5.actionPerformed(ContactEditor.java:249)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:618)
at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:160)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:233)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:163)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1359)
... 46 more
```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear you're not setting your content type for your message.

Comment: any idea how to do this then?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135593/setting-content-type-for-mimemessage) should cover it.

Answer (score 0):

Before you make the call to send the e-mail you can add:

```
MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
```

for detail see the link [DCH class error with JavaMail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521027/dch-class-error-with-javamail)

Answer (score 0):

The Java Activation Framework used by JavaMail is not configured correctly, in this case.

It doesn't know how to handle the multipart/mixed content type.

See [this](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=237257) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9614008/3107043) answer for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This message indicates that the DCH content handler for the multipart/mixed content-type could not be found in your classpath.

I'm not sure how you are creating the 'multipart' in your code sample but given the exception you are recieving it is likely you are using the default constructor which would explain the content-type of multipart/mixed.

You should not add mail cap mappings statically, you will run in to further problems if you don't resolve this properly.

I suggest checking your project dependencies and make sure the activation.jar is in your class path.

If you are using maven you can use:

mvn dependency:tree

Failing that you can add the activation framework to your project using the following dependency declarations:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Gradle Dependency:

```
'javax.activation:activation:1.1.1'
```